# SQL INSERT\UPDATE query using existing data

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am using SQL*Plus with Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.4.0.

I have a table `customer_address`:

```
no - customer number

type - 0 main, 1 delivery, 2 invoice

email - customer e-mail address
```

Every customer has an e-mail address set as type 0, for e.g.:

```
SELECT no, type, email FROM customer_address WHERE cunu = '1';

1,0,customer@domain.com
```

I need to copy e-mail address for every customer from type 0 to type 1?

When I do a test like `INSERT INTO customer_address (no, type, email) VALUES ('1','1','test@domain.com');` I see error messages like:

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
```

Can someone provide a correct example?

Comment: are you sure that you have no other not nullable columns in your table?

Comment: Thanks. Yes there are 2 other columns with NOT NULL but both are '0', I guess I need to include those anyway. What would be a correct example to copy the data though?

Comment: It seems the error is caused because the row already exists (somehow) so what I need is an `UPDATE` not `INSERT`. Can someone modify an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
insert into customer_address
   (no,type,email, primarykeyfieldofthetable, otherfields)
select
   no,'1',email, sequenceofprimarykey.nextval, otherfields
from
  customer_address
where type='0'
```

Comment: You can not copy the primary key. Probably your pk is generated by a sequence. In this case when you select the new value you should write customer_address_table_sequence.nextval instead of the field's name.

Comment: Thanks but can you explain in the example as I do not understand?

Comment: I modified the answer.

Comment: So if customer number is the primary key I would use `no.nextval`? Actually write `nextval`?

Comment: Probably there is a sequence in your system which generates the ids to the customer table's no field. But I don't know the name of the sequence. If you can find the original insert query then it should be mentioned there. Or you can check the sequences list in the all_sequences table.

Comment: If I specify a certain customer `WHERE type='0' AND no='1'` then I do not get the error. I only get the error when I do it on all customers?

Comment: I think the no='1' restricts the whole copy operation to only one customer. Anyway you should check which constraint is violated to avoid the violation. Maybe this helps: http://sivalingapandian.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/to-get-constraint-details-oracle-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

if you incluse all the fields in the correct order you can also avoid to specify them after the table name

```
INSERT INTO customer_address
     SELECT no,
            '1',
            email, 
            otherfields
       FORM customer_address
      WHERE cunu ='1'
        AND type='0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You ae getting the error, because you don't fill all not-null columns. There must be at least one column in the table that is not nullable and has no default value.

```
insert into customer_address (no, type, email, notnullcol1, notnullcol2)
  select no, 1 as type, email, notnullcol1, notnullcol2
  from customer_address
  where type = 0
;
```